# jQuery DataTables fnCreatedCell not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, datatables, cell

I'd like to change a cell's text color based on its value. However, the `fnCreatedCell` function is not being called when I add data to the table.

This is pretty weird considering I used `fnCreatedRow` with success. However, this could only color the entire row, which isn't the desired functionality.

I can see that the latter function is of type 'Callback', whereas `fnCreatedCell` is of type 'Columns'. So I assume I cannot use `fnCreatedCell` like `fnCreatedRow`, but how can I use it?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display cell-border"  id="example" ></table>');

        t = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columns": 
            [
                {"title": "c1", "data": "c1" },
                {"title": "c2", "data": "c2" },
            ],

            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) 
            {
                console.log(sData, cData, 'TEST'); // not being done
                if (sData > 30) 
                {
                    $(nTd).css('color', 'blue')
                }
            }
        });        
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

"*Type of 'Columns'*" means it is a part of the `columns` / `columnDefs` structures, i.e you have a `fnCreatedCell` (from 1.10.x as you are using you can name it `createdCell`) for each individual column. Example :

```
t = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
       {"title": "c1", "data": "c1" },
       {"title": "c2", 
        "data": "c2",
        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            console.log(sData, cData, 'TEST'); // not being done
            if (sData > 30) {
                $(nTd).css('color', 'blue')
            }
         }
       }
    ] 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`fnCreatedCell` should be used for each column. It is not a generic implementation for the entire datatabale. Please use below implementation.

```
t = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        {"title": "c1", "data": "c1",
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                console.log("fnCreatedCell");
            }
        },
       {"title": "c2", "data": "c2"}
    ] 
});
```